# Computational complexity of an algorithm involving permutations

Tags: complexity-theory, runtime-analysis, permutations

I'm interested in getting a precise estimate of the computational complexity of an algorithm I wrote involving permutations. Permutations are represented in my code as arrays of the integers $1$ through $n$ for some $n$, which can vary, and at least in the output (but perhaps not in the intermediate stages) the $n$th element of the array (with $1$-indexing) will never be $n$, unless the permutation is $[1,2]$. These are meant to represent infinite permutations with finite support.

The function is called `elem_sym_perms(perm,p,k)`, where $k\geq 1$ and $0\leq p\leq k$ are integers.

The basic step of the algorithm is to first add the pair `(perm,1000)` to the array `up_perm_list` and add `perm` to the array `total_list`. $1000$ was meant to be a larger length of a permutation than you would ever call this algorithm for. Could just as well make it $0$ and add special handling to treat it like infinity. I'm not sure whether python code is allowed here or if I should post pseudocode, not sure of the customs, but I'll start with pseudocode. **Arrays are 1-indexed.**

```
ALGORITHM

for each q from 1 to p:
    create empty array up_perm_list2
    for each up_perm, last_value in up_perm_list:
        let pos_list be the set of indices less than or equal to k such that up_perm[k]<last_value
        increase the length of up_perm by 1 by padding with len(up_perm)+1 at the end
        for each j from k+1 to len(up_perm):
            if j>=last_value:
                continue
            for each i in pos_list:
                if up_perm[i] < up_perm[j] and there are no indices r strictly between i 
                    and j such that up_perm[i]<up_perm[r]<up_perm[j]
                        create array up_perm2 equal to up_perm but swapping indices i and j
                        trim up_perm2 (if the value at the end is equal to its index, pop until this is no longer true)
                        add (up_perm2,up_perm[j]) to up_perm_list2
                        add up_perm2 to total_list
    set up_perm_list equal to up_perm_list2
```

The output is `total_list`. What is the asymptotic runtime of this algorithm as a function of the length of the permutation and $k$?

Chaining this algorithm on its own output and counting a given terminal permutation is #P-complete, but I think that's a function of the number of permutations blowing up exponentially.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami We're reducing it to the minimal representation of the permutation in an array, so pop the last value for as long as it is equal to its index.